# User removes specific child element

Tags: javascript

```
<textarea rows = "4" cols = "15" class = "sect"></textarea>
<textarea rows = "4" cols = "15" class = "sect"></textarea>
<textarea rows = "4" cols = "15" class = "sect"></textarea>
<textarea rows = "4" cols = "15" class = "sect"></textarea>

<script>
window.onload = function myFunction(){
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("sect");
for(var i = 0;i < x[i].length;i++){
  if(x[i].parentNode.children[i].ondblclick){
      x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

I want the user to double click on the element to remove it. So, if user double clicks on the 2nd "textarea" box, that specific element would be removed. My code above is as much as I have so far. Not sure what I'm doing wrong and very much appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Why are you testing to see if the dblclick event property equals an element?

Comment: DO you want jQuery solution or plain javascript solution?  You tagged the question with jQuery, but do not show any jQuery in your code example.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap them all into a container, set the handler on the container and use the event.target.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <textarea rows = "4" cols = 15" class = "sect"></textarea>
    <textarea rows = "4" cols = 15" class = "sect"></textarea>
    <textarea rows = "4" cols = 15" class = "sect"></textarea>
    <textarea rows = "4" cols = 15" class = "sect"></textarea>
</div>

var wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');
wrapper.addEventListener('dblclick', function ( event ) {
    wrapper.removeChild(event.target);
});
```

Comment: Note the wrapper div is not necessary in this case (you could iterate the `sect` elements and attach handlers individually as done in OP's example), but certainly simplifies the code a bit for the straight javascript solution.

Comment: I really try to avoid adding individual handlers to elements if I can help it, since it scales louzy past a certain point, uses more memory and forces me to edit the loop if I want to mix different modules to use the same handler later on. For 4 elements it won't matter, but I consider it a good practice to use event bubbling to a direct parent whenever it's appropriate. It's equivalent to jquerys delegate `$(container).on(event, child, fn)` which is the faster handler according to the protected SO answer for direct vs delegate.

Answer (score 0):

@Shilly has provided a good plain javascript answer.  A good jQuery solution (since you had jQuery tag on this question) could be:

```
$('.sect').on('dblclick', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pure javascript you can do this way:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("sect");

for(var i = 0;i < x.length;i++){
  x[i].addEventListener("dblclick", function (e) {
      this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add an `eventListener` on each `.sect` element (or whatever you want) and remove the `event.target`:

Native JS:

```
var elts = document.querySelectorAll(".sect");
for (var i = 0; i < elts.length; i++) {
    var elt = elts[i];
    elt.addEventListener('dbclick', function(evt) {
        document.body.removeChild(evt.target);
    }
}
```

jQuery (since you tagged jQuery when I wrote the question):

```
$(document).on('dbclick', '.sect', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```